# what is the name of this pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

What is the name of that kind of structure?
Or where can I read about that.

```
class A : public B < A > { ... }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).